# Why I cannot import transformations after installation in python using pip?

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am running python 3.8 and using pip to install many packages and inporting it. But when I try to install transforms and import it I get the following messages. Any help would be appreciated.

C:\Users\r.acharyya.CI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38>pip install transforms
Requirement already satisfied: transforms in c:\users\r.acharyya.ci\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (0.1)

C:\Users\buy.rtharyya.CI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38>pip install transforms
Requirement already satisfied: transforms in c:\users\r.acharyya.ci\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (0.1)

C:\Users\buy.rtharyya.CI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import transforms
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "C:\Users\r.acharyya.CI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transforms_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
> > > from .safe_html import safe_html, bodyfinder
> > > File "C:\Users\r.acharyya.CI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\transforms\safe_html.py", line 1, in 
> > > from sgmllib import SGMLParser, SGMLParseError
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sgmllib'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[transforms](https://pypi.org/project/transforms/#history), the only version is [0.1](https://pypi.org/project/transforms/0.1/)  released Aug 21, 2014. The code is obviously Python2-only. `sgmllib` was a module in the standard library https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sgmllib.html, deprecated since version 2.6.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in the link you can see he is using from data import transforms with python3.7      https://medium.com/@khodges42/how-to-get-started-diy-neurohacking-with-the-fastmri-dataset-and-why-you-should-6a02a6bb896e

Comment: @Creator This is clearly a different `transforms`, not the one you can install with `pip install transforms`.

Comment: It's https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastMRI/blob/master/fastmri/data/transforms.py so you need to install https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastMRI

Comment: It may be asking too much help. But I know how to install using pip. So how can I install from the link you gave me.

Comment: [Installation instructions](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastMRI#dependencies-and-installation). Linux-only as far as I can see.

Comment: I am using windows. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: In Windows there is WSL2 which runs Ubuntu which is exactly what's needed for fastMRI.

Comment: Thank you for your information;  I did install fastMRI in my Ubuntu virtual machine but still could not make the following line work : from data import transformations as T

Comment: `from fastmri.data import transformations as T`; `data` is a submodule of `fastmri` module.

Answer (score 1):

I used the command `pip install sgmllib3k` and it solve my issues.